# Using LINQ to Extract Specific Values from Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with multi-dimentioned arrays of `bool`, `int`, and various `struct`. The code loops through these arrays and performs some operation on specific values. For instance,

```
        for (int x = 0; x < this.Size.Width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.Size.Height; y++) {
                if (this.Map[x, y]) {
                    DrawTerrain(this.Tile[x, y].Location, Terrain.Water);
                }
            }
        }
```

I can do simple LINQ stuff, but I can't do what I would like. What I would like to do is use LINQ. Maybe something like

`from x in this.Map where x == true execute DrawTerrain(...)`

But, I don't understand how I can get the x and y locations or how to call a method in the LINQ statement.

Also, it would be great if I can put this code into a function and be able to call it with a delegate or a predicate? I don't know if delegate or predicate are the correct words.

```
    void Draw(Delegate draw, bool[,] map, struct[,] tiles) 
        from x in map where x == true draw(titles[x,y]).invoke;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ query syntax isn't really designed for working with 2-dimensional data structures, but you can write an extension method that will convert the 2D array into a sequence of values that contain the coordinates in the original 2D array and the value from the array. You'll need a helper type to store the data:

```
class CoordinateValue<T> {
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write the extension method (for any 2D array) like this:

```
IEnumerable<CoordinateValue<T>> AsEnumerable(this T[,] arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(0); j++)
      yield new CoordinateValue<T> { Value = arr[i, j]; X = i; Y = j; };
}
```

Now you can finally start using LINQ. To get coordinates of all elements from the 2D array such that the value stored in the element is `true`, you can use the following:

```
var toDraw = from tile in this.Map.AsEnumerable()
             where tile.Value == true
             select tile;

// tile contains the coordinates (X, Y) and the original value (Value)
foreach(var tile in toDraw)
    FillTile(tile.X, tile.Y);
```

This lets you specify some interesting conditions when filtering the tiles. For example if you wanted to get only diagonal elements, you could write:

```
var toDraw = from tile in this.Map.AsEnumerable()
             where tile.Value == true && tile.X == tile.Y
             select tile;
```

To answer your second question - if you want to encapsulate the behavior into the method, you'll probably need to use some `Action<...>` delegate to represent the drawing function that will be passed to the method. It depends on the type signature of your drawing method though.

Comment: My father says I need to try your way, but I get a compile error on "yield new CoordinateValue<T> { Value = arr[i, j]; X = i; Y = j; };" that say, "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement". Also, where do I put AsEnumerable, in CoordinateValue?

Comment: I GOT IT! Thank you so much. There should be , instead of ; in the yield statement. Also, AsEnumerable should be AsEnumerable<T>.

Comment: OMG. I was able to use an Action<CoordinateValue<T>> and it works. I don't know what I did, but I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* do it with LINQ if you work hard enough, but it would be a pain. It sounds like your first bit of code is absolutely fine.

Having a version of that which is generalised to take an action seems very reasonable though:

```
public delegate void Drawer(int x, int y, Tile tile);

public void Draw(Drawer drawer, bool[,] map, Tile[,] tiles) {
    for (int x = 0; x < this.Size.Width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < this.Size.Height; y++) {
            if (this.Map[x, y]) {
                drawer(x, y, tiles[x, y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you *really* want the LINQ version, it would be something like:

```
var query = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, Size.Width)
            from y in Enumerable.Range(0, Size.Height)
            where Map[x, y]
            select new { x, y };

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    DoWhatever(pair.x, pair.y, tiles[pair.x, pair.y]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following Linq query to get the x,y values then iterate over them to run your method.

```
var points = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, this.Size.Width - 1)
             from y in Enumerable.Range(0, this.Size.Width - 1)
             where this.Map[x, y]
             select new { X = x, Y = y };
foreach (var p in points)
    DrawTerrain(this.Tile[p.X, p.Y].Location, Terrain.Water);
```